# Movie/series identifiction from 80s/90s about time travel

Tags: story-identification

It was about a girl (probably). I remember only two episodes.

***First***

Girl traveled in time and came to a shore where a family of fishermen lived (poor husband and wife). They fed her and she showed them how to get salt from the sea. They became very happy because salt is like diamonds, cost a lot for that time. What was next I don't remember.

***Second***

Girl came to family of rich people, may be 18<sup>th</sup> century, in Europe. They were bad persons.

I googled a lot, and don't understand why I can't find. May be it's not American and popular show. I watched it in 2000s on Russian Culture Channel, when I was from 6 or 8 years old, so I really want to know what it is.